# Azure AD B2C signup page user-flow

Tags: javascript, html, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am working for Azure AD B2C. I have created a userflow for signin & signup page.I already rearranged user attributes from page layout section.
But i am still seeing email validation & password on top. I want them to shift to bottom of the form.
Can we do that through Azure or it requires customization? Thanks a lot
Here is the working snap:
[Signup page snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbYDL.png)

Expecting it to be something like this:
[I want it to look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UEuMs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge  what we can do from azure side is, Instead of creating our custom page content from scratch, We can customize Azure AD B2C's default page content.

Here is the list for default page content provided by Azure AD B2C,if we require any other customizations as you are aware we need to create our custom policy.

Default pages provided by Azure ADB2C

1.exception.html (Error page. This page is displayed when an exception or an error is encountered)
2.selfasserted.html(Self-Asserted page. Use this file as a custom page content for a social account sign-up page, a local account sign-up page, a local account sign-in page, password reset, and more. The form can contain various input controls, such as: a text input box, a password entry box, a radio button, single-select drop-down boxes, and multi-select check boxes.)
3.multifactor-1.0.0.html(Multi-factor authentication page. On this page, users can verify their phone numbers (by using text or voice) during sign-up or sign-in)
4.updateprofile.html (Profile update page. This page contains a form that users can access to update their profile. This page is similar to the social account sign-up page, except for the password entry fields.)
5.unified.html(Unified sign-up or sign-in page. This page handles the user sign-up and sign-in process. Users can use enterprise identity providers, social identity providers such as Facebook or Google+, or local accounts)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for posting your question.

As per my knowledge, we can Customize the user interface with HTML templates in Azure Active Directory B2c.
Azure AD B2C runs code in your customer's browser by using Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). At runtime, content is loaded from a URL you specify in your user flow or custom policy. Each page in the user experience loads its content from the URL you specify for that page. After content is loaded from your URL, it's merged with an HTML fragment inserted by Azure AD B2C, and then the page is displayed to your customer\End User.
When using your own HTML and CSS files to customize the UI, host your UI content on any publicly available HTTPS endpoint that supports CORS.
Here is the reference link for more information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Comment: Hi, Yes we can customize Azure B2C. But before doing that I just wanted to know if we can make my mentioned changes in Azure itself.